# getaddrinfo 11004 and python's httplib

Tags: python, httplib, getaddrinfo

I'm trying to get the rendered markup for http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/reviews/Breaded-Chicken-Cutlets-aka-Grandma-Jodys-Chicken-51114400; in theory the very same markup given by the 'View Page Source' menu option in Firefox.

I'm using a Python 2.7 script and the **httplib** library *[(http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html)*.  I've created an HTTPConnection object and when I try to get the markup via the HTTPResponse object's functions, I inevitably get a **getaddrinfo - 11004** error.  This script has been executed in Windows 7 and Ubuntu environments.

None of the other solutions for this error that I've read fit the bill:  I am not behind any firewall, and I have no problem pinging www.google.com.  I wonder if that website just doesn't conform to some standard I'm unaware of, as **I haven't been able to successfully ping my target website**.

I'm open to alternate approaches, let me know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out the `reqests` library.  It makes simple things like this much easier:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/reviews/Breaded-Chicken-Cutlets-aka-Grandma-Jodys-Chicken-51114400')

print r.text
```

Here are the docs: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Ran the above and verified it works.